# Необходимо заменить ип и порт в коде smali

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, smali

Нужно заменить ИП на 127.0.0.1, а порт на 1234. Я пробовал много раз, но не получилось ни разу. Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу. Вот smali код:

```
new-instance v4, Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress;
iget-object v5, p0, Lcom/rgame/net/ServerConnector;->a:Ljava/lang/String;
iget v6, p0, Lcom/rgame/net/ServerConnector;->b:I
invoke-direct {v4, v5, v6}, Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new-instance v4, Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress;
const-string v5, "127.0.0.1"
const/16 v6, 1234
invoke-direct {v4, v5, v6}, Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
```

Comment: Сделал так же, но приложение вылетает, когда доходит до этого кода. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вам перечислить все возможные 100500 причин? Как минимум нужно добыть логи вылета, чтобы иметь хоть какое-то представление о причине.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, причина была в редакторе апк. Теперь все работает.